# Process of install builder

Tags: installation, package

My requirement is to create a install builder . That downloads setup from the given link and start the installation.  My problem is that if  someone provides me a link and installation command and click on create setup then how do i generate a setup file. Generally these type of  software demands for a link of the software and the command line options and then generates  the setup.